# Not sure why I am getting a raster error (Error 000732) when incorporating parameter weights in my raster calculation?

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, error-000732, error-000539

Not sure if it is an error on my part, or Esri. I am just running a model in ModelBuilder that incorporates the weights for four of the parameters in the raster calculation. It seems to run find before I add four variant variables that use weights.

This is the equation I am putting in my raster calculator before I select 'Run':

```
%FHHChldWeight% * “%FHHChldDensity%” + %NoHighSchWeight% * “%NoHighSchDensity%” +
%MaleUnemWeight% * “%MaleUnemDensity%” + %PovertyWeight% * “%PovertyDensity%”
```

my raster calculation code (what gets calculated in the end) It seems its not calculating my first parameter ChildWeightr:

```
25*"FHHChldDensity"+"25" *"NoHighSchDensity" + "25"* "MaleUnemDensity" +"25" *PovertyDensity
```

but here is my traceback:

```
Executing (FHH Kernel): KernelDensity PittsburghBlkGrps ZFHHChld E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\FHHChldDensity 50 3000 "Square miles" Densities Planar #
Start Time: Friday, November 25, 2022 1:09:38 PM
Succeeded at Friday, November 25, 2022 1:09:51 PM (Elapsed Time: 12.93 seconds)
Executing (NoHighSch Kernel Density): KernelDensity PittsburghBlkGrps ZNoHighSch E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\NoHighSchDensity 50 3000 "Square miles" Densities Planar #
Start Time: Friday, November 25, 2022 1:09:52 PM
Succeeded at Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:05 PM (Elapsed Time: 12.73 seconds)
Executing (MaleUnem Kernel Density): KernelDensity PittsburghBlkGrps ZMaleUnem E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\MaleUnemDensity 50 3000 "Square miles" Densities Planar #
Start Time: Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:05 PM
Succeeded at Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:18 PM (Elapsed Time: 12.77 seconds)
Executing (Kernel Density (4)): KernelDensity PittsburghBlkGrps ZPoverty E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\PovertyDensity 50 3000 "Square miles" Densities Planar #
Start Time: Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:19 PM
Succeeded at Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:31 PM (Elapsed Time: 12.74 seconds)
Executing (Raster Calculator): RasterCalculator "25* "E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\FHHChldDensity" +"25" * "E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\NoHighSchDensity" + "25"* "E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\MaleUnemDensity" +"25" * "E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\PovertyDensity"" e:\downloads\gistforpro1\esripress\gistforpro\chapter10\tutorials\chapter10.gdb\poverty_index
Start Time: Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:34 PM
25* Raster(r"E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\FHHChldDensity") +"25" * Raster(r"E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\NoHighSchDensity") + "25"* Raster(r"E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\MaleUnemDensity") +"25" * Raster(r"E:\Downloads\GISTforPro1\EsriPress\GISTforPro\Chapter10\Tutorials\Chapter10.gdb\PovertyDensity")
ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec_DC684390_0C54_4F14_9EBF_B34DF3F2E1B1
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 9342, in Times
    return Wrapper(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 55, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 9340, in Wrapper
    return _wrapLocalFunctionRaster(u"Times_sa",
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset 25 does not exist or is not supported

Failed to execute (Raster Calculator).
Failed at Friday, November 25, 2022 1:10:36 PM (Elapsed Time: 1.11 seconds)
```

Not sure how to work around this, or why it's doing this or why I am getting this error.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work either, got an 9999 error when I tried to use double.

Comment: Can you make sure that the variable is represented correctly - %FHHChldWeight%. It is not finding the dataset, but if you look through the stack the value is never in quotes as the others are. The error refers to not being able to access a dataset. But could also point to a wrong variable.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In the model, set your weight parameters as a numeric type, either floating point (double type) or integer (long type).

In the raster calculator, cast your weights to numeric using

```
float("%weight param%")
```

or

```
int("%weight param%")
```

E.g.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @pixidust Did this answer solve your issue? If it did, you may choose to [accept to mark the question as answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Or if not, please provide feedback so the answer can be improved and help you or future users with the same problem.